# Mac App window stuck under the finder bar

Tags: macos, window-manager

I opened an app and the Dock was in the way so it automatically adjusted up and under the Finder. It seems to remember this position whenever I reopen it. I can "Zoom" but I really don't want to because it doesn't i the issue. I can only use the window in "Zoom Mode", then.

EDITS:

I'm running Leopard 10.5.8

Bring to front doesn't help.

Edit:

Spaces is the answer. Solved. Open spaes via hotkey and drg the window.

Comment: leopard or snow leopard (or tiger, or something else?)

Comment: "I can Zoom but i dont really want to" What does that mean? Can you get to the app and 'un-stick' it by zooming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hit F8 to view all the spaces and then moved the window like that. - Spaces don't show the Dock and Finder Bar in that view.